# Reducing a region in Google Earth Engine error for NDVI classification

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to classify a region using NOAA but after input the date to classify then it does not generate a chart and shows the error of region and chart.

The error for the region is this:

```
Line 151: Error in map(ID=20200123):
Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 28361501, but maxPixels allows only 10000000.
Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error. If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both.
```

for the chart it is

```
Error generating chart: Error in map(ID=20200123): Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 28361501, but maxPixels allows only 10000000. Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error. If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both.
```

This is my full code:

```
      var data = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CDR/AVHRR/NDVI/V5')
                      
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date(date_start, date_end))
                      // .median()  // .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
                      // .sort('system:time_start')
                   
                      //.map(function(data){return data.lt(0.18).and(data.gt(0.27))})
    
                      .map(function(data){return data.clip(AOI)});
    
     var col = data.select('NDVI').first()
    
    
      var ndvi2 =col
              .where(col.gt(0.18).and(col.lte(0.22)), 2)
              .where(col.gt(0.22).and(col.lte(0.27)), 3);
      var ndviChart = ui.Chart.image.series(col, AOI, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30);
      ndviChart.setOptions({
        title: 'Mean NDVI',
        vAxis: {title: 'NDVI', maxValue: 1},
        hAxis: {title: 'date', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 7}},
        maxPixels:90e9,
      });
        chartPanel.widgets().set(10, ndviChart);
      
       mapPanel.addLayer(NDVI_annual_recl,BandCompViz,'chart');
      }
       });
    
     mainPanel.add(submit);
```

Comment: Please no cross-posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822169/reducing-a-region-in-google-earth-engine-error-for-classification/70828923#70828923. Choose one site and delete the question in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you posted this question in Stack Exchange here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822169/reducing-a-region-in-google-earth-engine-error-for-classification/70828923#70828923. In case you missed it, here is my reply:

It looks like the AOI you are trying to calculate over is too large. You will want to either make the AOI smaller, reduce the scale of your image, or split the AOI into smaller pieces so that you can run your analysis. Earth Engine has a hard limit of 1e7 pixels per calculation, so you will want to make sure that the number of pixels inside your AOI is less than that.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your help ,it worked.

Comment: @WanjohiChristopher please accept the answer.